# How to redirect tensorboard to my server?

Tags: tensorflow, ssh, tensorboard

I have a distant computer (A) with a training on tensorflow. I run locally tensorboard on port 30080.

I redirect the port 30080 to my server B so in my computer A I run that command:

```
 ssh -R 30080:localhost:30080 user@mydomain.net
```

When I try to reach with my other computer C the page mydomain.net:30080 there is nothing. The port 30080 is open because I can use it for other application.

The only way I found to get tensorboard result on C is :

```
 ssh -L 30080:localhost:30080 user@mydomain.net:30080
```

And then on my computer C I can go on localhost:30080 to see tensorboard result.

How can I modify the pipeline to see the result on public page on my server B?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the option `--bind_all` while launching the tensorboard.

Comment: I try with that option but nothing happend when I go on my server page